# Pointers and references in functions

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a problem with a school homework. I have to write a few function, and I have problem with the ShiftPointerVal which argument is a pointer to int. This is the most important in that homework, I mean that argument. I have that issue: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment. Target of this function is to make a pointer bigger by one. I don't know how to write this function so the pointer to int can be an argument.

```
void ShiftPointerVal (int& pointer)
{
    &pointer = &pointer + 1;
}

void ShiftPointerRef (int *&pointer)
{
    pointer = pointer + 1;
}

void ShiftPointerPointer (int **pointer)
{
    *pointer = *pointer +1;
}

int main ()
{
    int number = 5;
    int* p_number = &number;

    std::cout << "\n----- 4 -----\n";
    std::cout << &number << "\t" << p_number << "\n";
    std::cout << *p_number << "\n";
    ShiftPointerVal (p_number);
    std::cout << &number << "\t" << p_number << "\n";
    std::cout << *p_number << "\n";


    std::cout << "\n----- 5 -----\n";
    std::cout << &number << "\t" << p_number << "\n";
    std::cout << *p_number << "\n";
    ShiftPointerRef (*&p_number);
    std::cout << &number << "\t" << p_number << "\n";
    std::cout << *p_number << "\n"; 

    std::cout << "\n----- 6 -----\n";
    std::cout << &number << "\t" << p_number << "\n";
    std::cout << *p_number << "\n";
    ShiftPointerPointer (&p_number);
    std::cout << &number << "\t" << p_number << "\n";
    std::cout << *p_number << "\n";
}
```

Comment: int& isn't a pointer, it's a reference, and in C++ references aren't allowed to be re-seated.

Comment: so how to take adress form argument if not by &?

Comment: int * px = &pointer;   // will give you a pointer-to-the-int-the-reference-is-an-alias-of, which you can then increment (e.g. px++; ) if you want (although it will be undefined behavior to do so, since p_number is pointing at a single int rather than into an array of ints).  However, that will still only modify the local variable px and not the int& argument, which I suspect is what you want to modify.  AFAIK C++ does not allow you to do what you are trying to do (which, if I understand it correctly, is that you want to change the underlying int that the 'pointer' argument is a reference to)

Comment: OTOH if your intent is to increment the value of the integer itself (i.e. to increment the value held by 'number' to 6), than a simple pointer = pointer + 1;  in your ShiftPointerVal() function will do that.

Comment: Btw I think you need to call either ShiftPointerVal(number) or ShiftPointerVal(*p_number);  calling ShiftPointerVal(p_number) won't compile.

Comment: `ShiftPointerVal (p_number);` is an error